# Node.js: Using the 'request-promise' module, how do I execute a function before I receive a response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request-promise

I want to get the time I sent the request and the time I get the response from the server, because some requests might take some time to process on the server side. I have this:

```
function httpRequestCall(options) {
    let timeJson.before = getTime();
    let myRequest = () =>{
       request(options)
           .then((response) => {
                let statusCode = JSON.stringify(response.statusCode);
                let responseData = response.body.data;

                console.log("Response: " + responseData);

                timeJson.after = getTime();
                httpTimes.push(timeJson); //array of all times
                checkRecursion(index++); //I'm using recursion

           .catch((err) => {
               console.log("Error: " + err);

               timeJson.after = getTime();
               httpTimes.push(timeJson);
               checkRecursion(index++);
            })

   }

   myRequest();
}
```

My question is: is there any way I can get the exact time the request is made? With the code above, I get the time right before making the request, which is not what I need since there can be some sort of network problem when making the request, and if that happens I'll have the wrong time.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the example with the network problem. What problem do you think of specifically, and what time do you expect then?

Comment: The problem might be that the request might not be made spontaneously, say a 3 second cut of broadband, which will make my time wrong. I need the time right after the request is made, before the response is received.

Comment: If my request is made almost instantly, then the above code will work for me, but the request might rarely be made after 1-n seconds (network, or some other problem that I cant think of right now), which isn't interesting for me, I need the garantee that the request was made

Comment: But the request *is* made immediately in that case, it just takes more time to reach the server? It's not like nodejs waits before making the request - it's just the OS (or router or some other middleware) queuing up the packets until the connection is available again.

Comment: Yes, exactly, It might take time to reach the server. I need the exact time it reached the server. Sorry, I should've made myself more clear.

Comment: Well, then just do the timing on the server side. That's where you should be measuring processing time anyway.

Comment: Your request wont know it hit the server until it gets some "received ping" back from the server.  If something like this was built into the request, you would run into the same network style issues on the other side.  IE what if there is a "3 second cut of broadband" returning the "received ping"